# How to re-run from the same iteration in "for" loop after terminating it by checking some "if" condition inside that "for" loop in R- programming?

Tags: r, for-loop, na, cvxr

I have a matrix of B rows and p columns to create, namely "beta_bootstrap". Now I am running a "for" loop for each c running from 1 to B. Each row at each iteration will finally store a vector of p components after some convex optimization with respect to that variable namely "v3". The optimized vector is named as "final_boot1". In some iterations, say "c-th" iteration ,after optimization, this vector returns as "NA" values for each p components.

Here comes my problem and what my intention is to execute. I want to omit that "c-th" iteration, want "c will be c-1", the "for" loop is terminated for that iteration, it will again go to start of that "for" loop, consider starting for "c-th" iteration. I entirely want to do this not to encounter any row containing "NA". Also optimization remains fruitful

How to re-run that "for" loop from "c-th" iteration again if I am terminating at "c"?

Towards that I did the following code. But later I realised "next" argument won't help my problem because it will entirely skip that "c-th" iteration and start from"c+1" afresh. So my code is flawed in that sense what I specifically require. I can't find what to do. Please help. Any notations you find difficult to understand, please let me know. Here is my code....

```
library(CVXR). ##for convex optimization

B=50 #bootstrap iterations to be made

beta_bootstrap = matrix(NA,B,p) # collect B copies of bootstrap estimate of lasso estimator

for(c in 1:B)
{
   G_boot = matrix(NA,1,n)
   for (j in 1:n)
   {
      G_boot[1,j]= rexp(1,1) ## extract n iid exp(1) r.v for each stage optimization in objective function.
   }

G_boot 

#perturbation quantities from known density Exp(1), n copies at each stage, repeat B times

## Next we do Bootstrap convex optimization though CVXR function

v3 = CVXR::Variable(p) 

##declaration: bootstrap estimate wrt which objective function is optimized

penalty_boot = (p_norm(v3,1))*lambda_opt ## penalty term in the objective fn through p_norm syntax.

##lambda_opt is a known scalar

zz= t(y*G_boot) ## a col vector consisting of component wise product of y and G_boot. Also * does component wise product and return a vector

l1= -sum((z%*%v3)*zz) ## %*% returns actually a scalar product

zz1= as.matrix(y-P_tilde) ## y, P_tilde we know beforehand 

l2= sum((z%*%v3)*zz1) 

zz2= t(G_boot) ## col vector G_boot

l3 = sum((logistic(z%*%v3))*zz2) ## logistic(z) is an atom for log(1+exp z) in cvxr

obj_boot = penalty_boot+l1+l2+l3   ## objective function for optimization 

prob_boot = Problem(Minimize(obj_boot)) ## minimisation of objective function

resultB = solve(prob_boot)
resultB

final_boot1 = resultB$getValue(v3)

final_boot1=as.vector(final_boot1)  ##final_boot1 giving NA values sometimes, which is my concern

##I know this if statement is flawed. Please help.

if(any(is.na(final_boot1))==TRUE)
{
   c=c-1
   next
}
final_boot2=as.matrix(final_boot1)

final_boot2

final_boot3 = t(final_boot2)

final_boot3 ## Minimizer Bootstrap estimator

beta_bootstrap[c,]= final_boot3  ## At c-th stage we store that bootstrap estimator of p components

}
beta_bootstrap ##This matrix is important to construct Bootstrap Percentile Intervals
```

Please help.

Comment: Try implementing a `?repeat` loop which can be `break`ed by condition.

Comment: @jay.sf can you please elaborate further?

Comment: You need to post a **minimal** reproducible example.  Cut all the unrelated junk, just keep the parts related to your question.

Comment: The loop iteration variable is available for inspection, unlike the variables you might create I sie a regular R function. Just rerun the code starting at n+1 where n is the inner loop variable. Or use `tryCatch`.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to change the for loop variable after the loop has started.  You will need a different approach, maybe building on a structure like:

```
for (i in 1:N){
  inner <- FALSE
  while (!inner){
    [...the code you want to repeat...]
    if (good) inner <- TRUE
  }
}
```

From the help ?'for':

> The seq in a for loop is evaluated at the start of the loop; changing
> it subsequently does not affect the loop. If seq has length zero the
> body of the loop is skipped. Otherwise the variable var is assigned in
> turn the value of each element of seq. You can assign to var within
> the body of the loop, but this will not affect the next iteration.
> When the loop terminates, var remains as a variable containing its
> latest value.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5913329/4413615